# How to provide Selenium from Nuget package with modified chromedriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, build, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm very new to what I'm about to describe, so if there's a better way of going about this, please let me know.

I'm attempting to modify the source code for chromedriver, and use that modified version w/ Selenium's WebDriver. What I've done so far is gotten the source code for chromedriver from Chromium, modified, and compiled it. I'm left with a list of dlls and the executable for this.

Previously, I used NuGet to obtain the Selenium.Webdriver and Selenium.Webdriver.Chromedriver packages, but I was confused on how exactly chromedriver was running. In the [solution_name]\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.77.0.3865.4000\driver\win32 folder, I saw that chromedriver.exe, and in the [solution_name]\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.77.0.3865.4000\build folder, I noticed a .targets file, which inside had a line which pointed to the .exe location. 
I thought it would be enough the replace the chromedriver.exe from NuGet w/ my custom built executable, and include the compiled dlls inside that folder as well. I ended up getting an error some dlls (such as base.dll, all files that I had included in that some directory) were missing.

Any idea of how I can get this configuration to work, or again, if there's an easier way of going about this to modify the source code of chromedriver and use that w/ Selenium's webdriver?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have built your custom `chromedriver`, then you can specify the modded driver's path before initializing the driver. This will force it to use the specified `chromedriver` instead of whichever one is in your `$PATH`

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```